# Installing Line Profiler on Spyder 5.1.5

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, profiler

I have Python 3.9. I am running Spyder 5.1.5 through the anaconda navigator. I am trying to install the line profiler using the anaconda prompt. I have run both
`conda install spyder-line-profiler -c spyder-ide` and `pip install spyder-line-profiler`. Both options tell me that the profiler has been installed.

When go to view>panes, I do not see the line profiler as an option. I tried adding the @profile header to one of my functions and running the regular profiler to see if it would work. It doesn't recognize the header. Do I need a different version of Spyder or Python to get the line profiler working?

Comment: That extension hasn't been updated recently - are you sure it is compatible with Spyder 5? The Conda Forge builds constrain to Spyder 4.

Comment: Yeah I've checked and it's not compatible with Spyder 5. @merv

Comment: Did you try going to the Run tab, and seeing if there is a Run profiler option?

Comment: @Banks Yes, but there is no run line profiler option.

Comment: I'm still having this issue with spyder-line-profiler=0.3.0 and spyder=5.3.3. Works fine on Spyder 4 in a different environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Versions have advanced since this question was asked, but I have a solution for my current version (Spyder 5.3.2).

**Solution**: `conda install spyder-line-profiler=0.3.1 -c conda-forge`.

**Reasons**:

- Version 0.3.0 is incompatible with Spyder 5.3.2 (see [Github](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-line-profiler/issues/70))
- Version 0.3.1 is currently unavailable on `spyder-ide`